# notification not repeating

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager

I built a notification for my app. It's working, in the sense that it pushes at the correct time, and it links to the correct activity when pressed.

However, I call it with a repeating alarm because I want it to shoot out on specific days. 
In my initial test, I set it to push every 5 seconds so I can check quickly that it is repeating correctly. After the initial push, once I clear it, the notification never reappears.

Here is my code in my main activity to set up the alarmManager:

```
private void notificationAlarm() {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 1);
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, 1);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 40);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    long interval = cal.getTimeInMillis()+5000;

    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this, alarmNotif.class);
    PendingIntent alarmPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    AlarmManager notifAlarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    //notifAlarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), alarmPendingIntent);
    notifAlarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), interval, alarmPendingIntent);


}
```

and the code inside my broadcastreceiver:

public class alarmNotif extends BroadcastReceiver {

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    NotificationManager notifManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    String title = "Don't forget to order sushi from Arbuckle!";
    String subTitle = "Order before 10 AM with Arbuckle App";
    Intent notifIntent = new Intent(context, SecureAppStarter.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notifIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notifBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
    .setContentTitle(title)
    .setContentText(subTitle)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    Notification notif = notifBuilder.getNotification();
    notifManager.notify(1, notif);
}
```

}

Comment: A little help? Woke up this moorning without any news. Wasted 5 hours of sleep!

Answer (score 0):

Well I figured it out.

The problem was FLAG_ONE_SHOT; it should be FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT.

This allows the notification to be repeated at the desired intervals.

Voila!